# Getting a "File doesn't exist" error when trying to create a file

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write to a file that doesn't exist. I was told that when using `"w"` it would create the file if it doesn't exist. However this did not work and returned an error. I then added a line using `"x"` to create the file. This still returned an error.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brain\Documents\Python projects\Calendar\Calendar.py", line 22, in <module>
    day = open(today+".txt", "x")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '6/11/2021.txt'
```

Here is the code:

```
print("You do not have any reminders for today.")
print("Would you like to make some?")
newtoday = input().lower()
if newtoday == "yes":
    filename = open("filenames.txt", "w")
    filename.write(today)
    day = open(today+".txt", "x")
    day.close()
    day = open(today+".txt", "w")
    print("What would you like the title of the reminder to be?")
    title = input()
    print("Add any extra details below e.g. time, place.")
    det = input()
    day.write(title+": "+det, "(x)")
    filename.close()
    day.close()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error for "w".

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve]. Looking at above code, it's clear that e.g. `today` is undefined an that therefore the code can't possibly work. This makes it really bad for use in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `today` is a string containing `/` characters, `day = open(today+".txt", "x")` will read this string as a path to create the file in.
Your `today` variable contains `6/11/2021`, so it will look for the directory structure `6/11` and in that folder it will try to create the file `2021.txt`. Since he can't find those directories, the instruction will fail. You can try to format your file name `6-11-2021.txt`. If you do want to use the directories, you can parse `today` and create directories using [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir)

Comment: I just changed the variable today to use - instead of /, thanks.

Comment: If you found this helpful, please close the question by accepting this as an answer.